# "Learning" to parameterize Hermitian matrices with a basis using neural networks

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm interested in using neural networks to "learn" how to write down Hermitian matrices, specifically those which are defined over spaces with a specific tensor product structure. The simplest example of what I have in mind is writing down an arbitrary $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrix $A$ in terms of the following basis:

$$A = a_{0}I + a_{1}\sigma_{x} + a_{2}\sigma_{2} + a_{3}\sigma_{3},$$

$$\sigma_{x} = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\sigma_{y} = \begin{bmatrix}0&-i\\i&0\end{bmatrix},\sigma_{z} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}$$

and the $a_{i}$ are real numbers. More generally, the idea is to work with matrices which can be decomposed into a basis of matrices, analogous to what we've done with $A$. Is there a neural network structure which is useful for this task? I think it should be possible to do this by imagining that each of the $a_{i}$ are tunable parameters, and try to minimize your favorite norm between the resulting matrix predicted by the network and the ground truth, but I'm not sure what kind of structure is natural for this task. Any advice for how this could be done would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this could be achieved by direct projection to the Hermitian subspace, in stead of using NNs.